# Nuxt.js / Wordpress website needs XMLHttpRequest endpoint to come from HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, nuxt.js

I had a site built by a developer using Nuxt.js and Wordpress and after moving to a new server it seems that there is request to a none https url which is causing issues and not allowing content to load. That developer has stopped responding so I was hoping to get some advice on what can be done to fix the issue.

I checked the admin-ajax.php file but didn't see anything making this request. Also, I couldn't find the wp-json folder.

> The page at 'https://aerial.6thsensefitness.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://aerial.6thsensefitness.com/**wp-json/nuxt/v1/menu**'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
>
> The page at 'https://aerial.6thsensefitness.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://aerial.6thsensefitness.com/**wp-json/nuxt/v1/settings**'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
>
> The page at 'https://aerial.6thsensefitness.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://aerial.6thsensefitness.com**/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php**'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

- if you don't have the original Nuxt (VueJS) code and/or
- you cannot get the developer to respond and help and/or
- if you cannot modify the requests to HTTPS, then you have a problem.

The problem is that even if you get your site working, browsers (like Google Chrome) will categorize your site as "mixed content", and won't honor your SSL certificate - showing your site as "Not Secure".

Other:

1. The **wp-json** folder does not exist as a folder. It's the base of the **Wordpress REST API** endpoints. (More on this: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) The *http://aerial.6thsensefitness.com/wp-json/nuxt/v1/menu* is called a route (or endpoint in this case), and it merely instructs your website to do something that is associated with this *route*. From the route name, I'd say that it requests the menu for your site.
2. **http://aerial.6thsensefitness.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php** is not making any requests here, but it is requested in this *XMLHttpRequest* (that's why you don't find anything related to your problem in that file). You have to find the place(es) where this request is sent.

You might try:

- **Really Simple SSL** - https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/ This Wordpress plugin might have a chance to help you (I use it on a lot of sites that had to be migrated to SSL, but haven't tried it on AJAX requests, only HTML content, like image sources, internal- and external links, etc.)
- **Find the requests in your theme/plugin files**, and correct them. Unfortunately, it's a Nuxt site (I love Nuxt, but in your case, it's unfortunately), and that means that you have a codebase that was generated from a source automatically (from VueJS, probably using Webpack) - optimized, bundled, uglified, etc. If this is true, you'll have a hard time finding these requests, and modifying them may break your theme.